# The program arguments text box in codeblocks 10.05 is not visible

Tags: ubuntu, codeblocks

My environment is ubuntu 11.10.When I am trying to debug the program and add program arguments in the program argument text box, I find that it is squeezed into a line. And there is no way to make it wider. Has the similar problem bothered you? I checked under windows, and in the same place there is indeed a text box.And I have checked my wxWidget is up to date. Thanks!

Seems that I am not permitted to post images, so sorry if the description is not clear enough.

***Made a check and found that I was able to input in the line styled text box, maybe I changed the fonts and this is a small bug.***