# Program arguments text box content in codeblocks 10.05 is not visible

Tags: c++, debugging, ubuntu, codeblocks

Duplicate : [The program arguments text box in codeblocks 10.05 is not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004759/the-program-arguments-text-box-in-codeblocks-10-05-is-not-visible)

I want to debug code which takes command line arguments in C++ using Codeblock IDE.I googled and read that "Project-> Set program's aregumnets" can be use to pass the command line arguments. But when I choose that option the textbox is not editable. Please refer the snapshot below for your kind reference.

[image]

Any thoughts on on how to fix this.

**Edit:**
I am on Ubuntu.
I am able to tab in `Program arguments` but unable to increase the size of text box.Even maximising the window is not doing any help. I can see that I am able to type.

Reinstalling did not help.

I found this link
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1906791
which talks about hacking "I can work round by hacking the project.cbp file and adding a line  but this is messy."
Can someone please elaborate how this workaround might work for me. Thanks.

Comment: Could run it from the command line if all else fails.

Comment: My arguments box seems to be working fine and I can't seem to find any bugs around.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to reinstall it really. Mine's for Windows too, so it might differ in that regard.

Comment: Are you able to "tab in" to the arguments field?

Comment: Being on ubuntu, you should also consider Terminal+gdb for debugging, if you haven't already. It will save you from such GUI troubles.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution here [I don't know how to use Project->Set programs' arguments to provide arguments to](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,15376.0.html).

Basically, what you need to do is to substitute select_target.xrc file in /usr/share/codeblocks/manager_resources.zip with the one in the attached file  select_target.zip. The attached file can be only available when you log on the forum.